# Adding service reference not generating correctly Reference.cs

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have a Java Server which is running on a virtual box Debian OS,

Anyway a WSDL file is created on the server side and from Visual Studio I am consuming the web service. The service is discovered and I am adding this service reference, however, When I try to build I get this error:

> *'WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings' does not
>   contain a definition for
>   'WindowsFormsApplication2_TravelAgency_TravelBooking' and no extension
>   method 'WindowsFormsApplication2_TravelAgency_TravelBooking' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Web
>   References\TravelAgency\Reference.cs  42*

This relates to this in `Reference.cs`:

```
this.Url = global::WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.WindowsFormsApplication2_TravelAgency_TravelBooking;
```

`WindowsFormsApplication2_TravelAgency_TravelBooking` is underlined in red.

I do not have a clue what has happened and will add all information required not sure what else to add.

EDIT:

All the code I have is as follows

`Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

And `Form1.cs` and `Form1.cs[Design]`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication2.TravelAgency;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TravelBooking tb = new TravelBooking();

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If I do this in Netbeans and create a Java Gui(just to test) it works fine and works great. So this is why I believe it is something to do with the generated code

Comment: Is there a class named WindowsFormsApplication2_TravelAgency_TravelBooking anywhere and what namespace is it in?

Comment: From what you posted it seems like the Service is trying to get that from your App.config, check your service configuration (right click on Service node and "Configure Service reference...")

Comment: Updated my post. everything else is autogenerated from the Add Service Reference.

@VoidMain What should I look for in my service configuration

Comment: Is the service reference directly in the same project, or is it included in a library which is being referenced?

Comment: Hmmm, NVM about service configuration, i think i know what kind of problem you have, Simply choose the properties of the web service and change the "Url Behavior" from "Dynamic" to "Static".

Comment: @VoidMain:: I had the same issue with my project but your solution works for me. Can you please tell me what is the problem in dynamic ?
Instead of comment please give it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others while finding .
user700786:please accept the answer .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with dynamic URLs, when you don't have an URL set up in your App.config it gives you that error, here is an explanation on how to change it from Static to Dynamic with added value, it shows the code that gets generated in both cases, when the URL is set to dynamic, the autogenerated code will try to get it from App.config via `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` or, in newer versions, from the Application properties (wich is even worse) and there is where you get the exception if you don't have it, the generated code checks for nulls but doesn't catch the exception.

You can verify this by yourself, change the URL to Dynamic and check the generated code.
A simple solution, if you don't need to change the URL later, is to set it to Static, another solution is to create the entry in App.config or, create the property in the project for .NET 4+

Hope this helps